# UI Elements not showing up on Android Virtual Device

Tags: java, android

I have just started learning Android and following the tutorials from the [Android site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html). I have followed it exactly. The small program is suppose to show a `textfield` and a `button`. The "activity_main.xml" is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" 
        android:layout_weight="1" />

     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and the "strings.xml" is :

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</resources>
```

The "MainActivity.java" is the default which I have not done anything to it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run the program, the Emulator shows up but the `Textfield` and the `Button` never shows up. I am using Eclipse on Windows machine.  The Eclipse and the Android Development Tools are all freshly installed.

Its my first Android app and just don't know why the textfield and button are not showing up.

### Edit

When I run the program, I also get this warning:

```
    [2012-08-30 08:42:59 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.

    [2012-08-30 08:42:59 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    [2012-08-30 08:42:59 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    [2012-08-30 08:42:59 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    ...
```

Comment: is there any error on logcat? your layout should show the textfield and button already

Comment: I run your code and its perfectly works.

Comment: @aprian  Yes there is a warning. I have included it in my post

Comment: Its only waring not the error.

Comment: I don't know if am missing any library or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
```

to

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

For the first time when you run on emulator it will take time to display output screen. From the next time onwards it will display faster. Did you wait for some time and check that?

Comment: Yes. As am talking now the emulator has been running for about 3mins. Which Element should i make the changes? since  "android:layout_width" attributes can be found in LinearLayout, EditText and Button elements. Or i have to change it in all the elements?

Comment: change it in EditText. Close the emulator once and run it again.

Comment: Are you getting any lock screen or any android image on the emulator screen? or an  blank screen?

Comment: @swathi Thanks. I get the Android image on the screen. Only the Android image appears when i run

Comment: IS THERE ANYBODY OUT THERE TO HELP ME FIX THIS PROBLEM. AM STUCK AND CAN'T GO FURTHER WITHOUT SOLVING THIS ISSUE.

Comment: Now without closing the emulator run the program again and check once.

Comment: @swathi I did what you said and a second Emulator pops up but stays blank continuously with no Android image.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16022/discussion-between-swathi-and-eddy-freeman)